# Error in if (REML) p else 0L : the condition has length > 1

Tags: null, lme4, glmm

I am trying to calculate the null model as follows:

```r
null <- lmer(Binomialvariable ~  1 + (1|ID), data=data, REML=F)
```

and I get the following error message:

> Error in if (REML) p else 0L : the condition has length > 1

I was wondering if someone knows what's wrong, and how I can fix it. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

I have tried to add a control variable instead of the 1 value, which gives the same answer. Then I tried REML = T, or remove REML, which gave another error message: object 'REML' not found

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99% sure that you have assigned a vector of length >1 to `F` in the global environment.

```r
library(lme4)
F <- c(1,2,3)
null <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + (1|Subject), sleepstudy, REML = FALSE)  ## fine
null <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + (1|Subject), sleepstudy, REML = F)
## Error in if (REML) p else 0L : the condition has length > 1
```

Best practices:

- always use `FALSE` instead of taking the `F` shortcut
- don't assign values to built-in R objects (`F`, `T`, `c`, `t`, etc etc etc)

Comment: Yes that's a very point, thank you!

Comment: so I have changed it, and now I have the following message: null=lmer(ScYN ~  1 + (1|ID), data=data, REML= FALSE) 
Error in mkRespMod(fr, REML = REMLpass) : response must be numeric

Comment: what is your `binomialVariable`? If you want to do logistic regression you need use `glmer(..., family = "binomial")`

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thank you very much, I really appreciate it.